# How can I find the zenith over a uk location on a previous date

Tags: astronomy

Does any one know how I can find out what was the position of the zenith over a uk location, for example, at midday on the 13th of January 2013?

Comment: There is plenty of planetarium software that does that for you. For London I find the sun to reach 17 degrees 6 minutes on that date with a program called Stellarium. Then there are sites like http://www.esrl.noaa.gov/gmd/grad/solcalc/azel.html which also can tell you the elevation of the sun as a function of location and time.

Comment: @CuriousOne that should be an answer

Comment: How accurate does it need to be? @CuriousOne the OP is asking for the position of the zenith, not the position of the Sun, but yes, free planetarium software like Stellarium can give you a reasonably exact answer.

Comment: @RobJeffries: Of course! My mistake. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How accurate does it need to be? Zenith has a declination equal to the latitude. RA=7h30m is approximately overhead at midnight on Jan 13th so add 12 hours for middday. So 19h20m, +53 would be about right for a UK location on Jan 13th.

Planetarium software like [Stellarium](http://www.stellarium.org/en_GB/) allows you to set your location and look at the sky on any date/time.

Comment: I use also Stellarium. Yes ! I understand now, ty